# Powershell get all strings between curly braces in a file

Tags: regex, powershell

```
Filecontent = "Hello this is {{Santa}} from far-far-away coming to your {{country}}.

I like {{world}} with lot of {{Green}}.
You always made me feel {{Happy}} <Testing>"
```

I want to get result:

```
Santa
country
Green
Happy
```

I tried with powershell + regex: `(?<=.*{{)\w+?(?=}}.*)` but it only get me if there is only one instance of curly braces {{xxx}}.

Thank you

Comment: Does powershell have variable length lookbehinds? Maybe if its uses Dot-Net regex.

Comment: The fastest way is to use a capture group to separate the text.  `{{(\w+)}}` And an fyi, in your `\w+?` the `?` is not needed.

Comment: I was actually unable to replicate the issue with PowerShell v4. `[RegEx]::Matches($Filecontent,"(?<=.*{{)\w+?(?=}}.*)").value` returns all expected words.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - That's odd, usually `.*` cause engines to seek right to the end and work backwards causing the next match to fail, leaving only one match.

Comment: @sln .Net actually has a fairly robust and flexible RegEx engine. You might be surprised how tolerant it is for things like that. I'm pretty sure it's working like it is because that's a look behind, so it finds the double curly brackets, and then validates the lookbehind, it doesn't execute the lookbehind first.

Comment: You're probably right. If anything it finds the first `\w` then validates the lookbehind. If ok, it finds the next word(s) where the lookahead is validated. This translates into `(?<={{)\w+(?=}})` making it simpler and variably unnecessary.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - you are correct. It's my bad on how I was initially coded it. 
Here is my initial script with $pattern set to (?<=.*{{)\w+?(?=}}.*)
Get-Content $path | Foreach {if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern)) {
               $arr += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern)
                }
            }

Comment: I guess there is a stickler here where `{{.*?}}` matches `{{this{{matches{{this}}`but}}not this}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PS D:\> $Filecontent = "Hello this is {{Santa}} from far-far-away coming to your {{country}}.

I like {{world}} with lot of {{Green}}.
You always made me feel {{Happy}} <Testing>"

PS D:\> [Regex]::Matches($filecontent, '(?<={{)(.*?)(?=}})') | Select -ExpandProperty Value

Santa
country
world
Green
Happy
```

Where the regular expression `'(?<={{)(.*?)(?=}})'` tests: must be `{{` to the left, `}}` to the right, capture everything in the middle - non-greedy (stay within one bracket pair).

Comment: *capture everything in the moddle -non-greedy... Thank you. You saved many of my hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
(?<={{).*?(?=}})
```